# How do I force opening braces to share the previous code line?

Tags: uncrustify

Using the [Uncrustify](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uncrustify) tool I would like to apply the [1TBS style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS_.28OTBS.29), which places braces like this:

```
if (x < 0) {
    printf("Negative");
}
```

How do I do this? I can't seem to find the right options.

Comment: What do you mean by "opening braces to share the previous code line?" Opening braces to be on the same line (not alone on a line)? Or something else? Perhaps provide an example of undesirable formatting?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to set `nl_if_brace` to ignore/add/remove/force.

Also, check the `sp_else_brace` and `sp_brace_else` options. Set it to 1, otherwise your code will end up with code such as:

```
if (condition){
```

instead of

```
if (condition) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called UniversalIndentGui that lets you play with Uncrustify's various tersely-worded settings and see immediate impact on a block of sample code.

[Screenshots of UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php)